# Image Neighbourhood Processing in Haskell

Tags: image, haskell, image-processing, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell, and trying to learn it by thinking in terms of image processing.

So far, I have been stuck thinking about how you would implement a neighbourhood-filtering algorithm in Haskell (or any functional programming language, really).

How would a spatial averaging filter (say 3x3 kernel, 5x5 image) be written functionally? Coming from an entirely imperative background, I can't seem to come up with a way to either structure the data so the solution is elegant, or not do it by iterating through the image matrix, which doesn't seem very declarative.

Comment: This is a rather domain specific problem, I think. You could attract more attention by including some sample code in another language, I think. The [repa](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial#Example:_parallel_image_desaturation) package is intended parallel data processing and has a good tutorial which includes some image processing examples. Also look at the [repa-examples](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-examples-3.3.1.1/src/examples/Blur/src-repa/Main.hs) package, specifically the "blur" example.

Comment: You could look at how the [repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) and [repa-devil](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-devil) libraries do it.

Comment: There was a great blog post on how comonads provide a straight-forward method for neighborhood operation on images (http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-11-27-comonads-image-processing.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with neighborhoods is easy to do elegantly in a functional language. Operations like convolution with a kernel are higher order functions that can be written in terms of one of the usual tools of functional programming languages - lists.

To write some real, useful code, we'll first play pretend to explain a library.

#### Pretend

You can think of each image as a function from a coordinate in the image to the value of the data held at that coordinate. This would be defined over all possible coordinates, so it would be useful to pair it with some `bounds` which tell us where the function is defined. This would suggest a data type like

```
data Image coordinate value = Image {
    lowerBound :: coordinate,
    upperBound :: coordinate,
    value      :: coordinate -> value
}
```

Haskell has a very similar data type called [`Array` in `Data.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html). This data type comes with an additional feature that the `value` function in `Image` wouldn't have - it remembers the value for each coordinate so that it never needs to be recomputed. We'll work with `Array`s using three functions, which I'll describe in terms of how they'd be defined for `Image` above. This will help us see that even though we are using the very useful `Array` type, everything could be written in terms of functions and algebraic data types.

```
 type Array i e = Image i e
```

`bounds` gets the bounds of the `Array`

```
 bounds :: Array i e -> (i, i)
 bounds img = (lowerBound img, upperBound img)
```

The `!` looks up a value in the `Array`

```
 (!) :: Array i e -> i -> e
 img ! coordinate = value img coordinate
```

Finally, `makeArray` builds an `Array`

```
 makeArray :: Ix i => (i, i) -> (i -> e) -> Array i e
 makeArray (lower, upper) f = Image lower upper f
```

`Ix` is a typeclass for things that behave like image coordinates, they have a `range`. There are instances for most of the base types like `Int`, `Integer`, `Bool`, `Char`, etc. For example the `range` of `(1, 5)` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. There's also an instances for products or tuples of things that themselves have `Ix` instances; the instance for tuples ranges over all combinations of the ranges of each component. For example, `range (('a',1),('c',2))` is

```
[('a',1),('a',2),
 ('b',1),('b',2),
 ('c',1),('c',2)]`
```

We are only interested in two functions from the `Ix` typeclass, `range :: Ix a => (a, a) -> [a]` and `inRange :: Ix a => a -> (a, a) -> Bool`. `inRange` quickly checks if a value would be in the result of `range`.

#### Reality

In reality, `makeArray` isn't provided by `Data.Array`, but we can define it in terms of `listArray` which constructs an `Array` from a list of items in the same order as the `range` of its `bounds`

```
import Data.Array

makeArray :: (Ix i) => (i, i) -> (i -> e) -> Array i e
makeArray bounds f = listArray bounds . map f . range $ bounds
```

When we `convolve` an array with a kernel, we will compute the neighborhood by adding the coordinates from the kernel to the coordinate we are calculating. The `Ix` typeclass doesn't require that we can combine two indexes together. There's one candidate typeclass for "things that combine" in base, `Monoid`, but there aren't instances for `Int` or `Integer` or other numbers because there's more than one sensible way to combine them: `+` and `*`. To address this, we'll make our own typeclass `Offset` for things that combine with a new operator called `.+.`. Usually we don't make typeclasses except for things that have laws. We'll just say that `Offset` should "work sensibly" with `Ix`.

```
class Offset a where
    (.+.) :: a -> a -> a
```

`Integer`s, the default type Haskell uses when you write an integer literal like `9`, can be used as offsets.

```
instance Offset Integer where
    (.+.) = (+)
```

Additionally, pairs or tuples of things that `Offset` can be combined pairwise.

```
instance (Offset a, Offset b) => Offset (a, b) where
    (x1, y1) .+. (x2, y2) = (x1 .+. x2, y1 .+. y2)
```

We have one more wrinkle before we write convolve - how will we deal with the edges of the image? I intend to pad them with `0` for simplicity. `pad background` makes a version of `!` that's defined everywhere, outside the `bounds` of an `Array` it returns the `background`.

```
pad :: Ix i => e -> Array i e -> i -> e
pad background array i =
    if inRange (bounds array) i
    then array ! i
    else background
```

We're now prepared to write a higher order function for `convolve`. `convolve a b` convolves the image `b` with the kernel `a`. `convolve` is higher order because each of its arguments and its result is an `Array`, which is really a combination of a function `!` and its `bounds`.

```
convolve :: (Num n, Ix i, Offset i) => Array i n -> Array i n -> Array i n
convolve a b = makeArray (bounds b) f
    where
        f i = sum . map (g i) . range . bounds $ a
        g i o = a ! o * pad 0 b (i .+. o)
```

To `convolve` an image `b` with a kernel `a`, we make a new image defined over the same `bounds` as `b`. Each point in the image can be computed by the function `f`, which `sum`s the product (`*`) of the value in the kernel `a` and the value in the `pad`ded image `b` for each offset `o` in the `range` of the `bounds` of the kernel `a`.

#### Example

With the six declarations from the previous section, we can write the example you requested, a spatial averaging filter with a 3x3 kernel applied to a 5x5 image. The kernel `a` defined below is a 3x3 image that uses one ninth of the value from each of the 9 sampled neighbors. The 5x5 image `b` is a gradient increasing from `2` in the top left corner to `10` in the bottom right corner.

```
main = do 
    let
        a = makeArray ((-1, -1), (1, 1)) (const (1.0/9))
        b = makeArray ((1,1),(5,5)) (\(x,y) -> fromInteger (x + y))
        c = convolve a b
    print b
    print c
```

The `print`ed input `b` is

```
array ((1,1),(5,5))
[((1,1),2.0),((1,2),3.0),((1,3),4.0),((1,4),5.0),((1,5),6.0)
,((2,1),3.0),((2,2),4.0),((2,3),5.0),((2,4),6.0),((2,5),7.0)
,((3,1),4.0),((3,2),5.0),((3,3),6.0),((3,4),7.0),((3,5),8.0)
,((4,1),5.0),((4,2),6.0),((4,3),7.0),((4,4),8.0),((4,5),9.0)
,((5,1),6.0),((5,2),7.0),((5,3),8.0),((5,4),9.0),((5,5),10.0)]
```

The `convolve`d output `c` is

```
array ((1,1),(5,5))
[((1,1),1.3333333333333333),((1,2),2.333333333333333),((1,3),2.9999999999999996),((1,4),3.6666666666666665),((1,5),2.6666666666666665)
,((2,1),2.333333333333333),((2,2),3.9999999999999996),((2,3),5.0),((2,4),6.0),((2,5),4.333333333333333)
,((3,1),2.9999999999999996),((3,2),5.0),((3,3),6.0),((3,4),7.0),((3,5),5.0)
,((4,1),3.6666666666666665),((4,2),6.0),((4,3),7.0),((4,4),8.0),((4,5),5.666666666666666)
,((5,1),2.6666666666666665),((5,2),4.333333333333333),((5,3),5.0),((5,4),5.666666666666666),((5,5),4.0)]
```

Depending on the complexity of what you want to do, you might consider using more established libraries, like the oft recommended [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa), rather than implementing an image processing kit for yourself.